# Why does visual studio need a solution file for nodejs projects?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to make a nodejs application that could be edited using IDEs/editors other than visual studio, and was wondering why a solution file was needed, as dependencies are managed by npm.

Comment: What tools do you use?

Comment: The builtin Typescript and Node.js support.

Comment: Not an anwser but you should consider using Visual Studio **Code**, a very light code editor with project management features (you can setup tasks, debug nodejs apps, easy source control...) and no solution file created :)

Comment: I had already looked into vscode, and while it was incredibly interesting, the lack of good vim support turned me away from it (it was missing many key features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution file holds a lot of data to setup your IDE. Most IDE's store some project specific data in your project root. The solution will just map out the actions of the run/debug actions, and specify other project specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Because solution file contains reference of assembly files and other dependencies. You can check it by opening solution file in notepad.